# BSODS when XMP is enabled

Tags: memory, xmp

Lately , I was experiencing many BSODS when I have enabled XMP. Right now , I have disabled XMP and the system is stable. I am trying to figure out the problem since I have done many searches with no solution for my problem . However , I have noticed something , but before mentioning it, here is my system specifications :

1- Aorus B550 Master

2- Ryzen 7 5800x

3- RTX 3070 gaming OC Gigabyte

4- 8 Gb X4 Aorus RGB memory 4400 Mhz

What I have noticed is that my CPU specs  states the following :

> System Memory : System Memory Specification Up to 3200MHz

When XMP is enabled , the speed is the rated speed of the RAM  ( i.e. 4400 Mhz ) but according to the CPU , the system memory specification should be up to 3200 MHz. So is the problem ? Or the memory specification of the CPU can be violated  ( overclocking) without causing these many BSODS in the short term ??

Comment: Have you checked for a BIOS update? Have you contacted the motherboard vendor asking if this is a known issue? What's the error code when you have a BSOD?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes , I am using the latest BIOS version , F13H.  Yes I have contacted GIGABYTE and their answer was simply send us  a screenshot for the memory speed to see at what speed the memory is working on your platform . A useless answer. The crashes were all related to memory issues such as IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL and KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED. But can exceeding the memory specification by 1200 Mhz  cause BSODS crashes ?

Comment: @spikey_richie I have done memory test with memtest86 two times  and every time I get zero errors.